# Joomla - how to hightlight the menu item for active page

Tags: joomla

How do you highlight the menu item of the active page?

Thanks!
Steph

Answer (score 6):

Please use following Css to Highlight selected/ active/ Current menu item

```
.menu ul ul{padding-left:10px;}
.menu ul li.active a{font-weight:bold;}
.menu ul li.active ul a{font-weight:normal;}
.menu ul li.active ul li.active a{font-weight:bold;}
```

This will work 100%.

Answer (score 4):

AFAIK the active menu position should have a special css class assigned to it. The class is probably called "active". You can target this class with some css rules and you should be done.

Comment: Silvo is correct, you'll see different classes and ids added to the menu itms such as .active or #current. You then need to create your CSS to highlight the item.

Answer (score 0):

That's very easy i just found it.
That you have to do overrode for css such as a:link, a:hover, a:visited are using white colour but you need grey colour instead for active page you just make anything the same and put !important behind that in #active_menu as example :

```
#main a:link, #main a:hover, #main a:visited {colour:#FFF;}

#active_menu {#CCC !important;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Try this Css

```
#menu ul li.active a{background-color:#eee;color:#333;
                     border-bottom:1px solid #eee;}
```

Comment: Please include explanation of what your code does and how it answers the question. If you get a code snippet as an answer, you may not know what to do with it. Answer should give the OP and future visitors guidance on how to debug and fix their problem. Pointing out, what the idea behind your code is, greatly helps in understanding the issue and applying or modifying your solution. Also better formatting of the code would help readability.