# CSS active menu item

Tags: css, joomla, menu

Hi I'm trying to modify a web template which doesn't have different colors for active menu items. I've tried various changes to be able to adjust this. Any ideas? Here is the css:

```
/** TOP MENU        **/

.top_menu .moduletable {
margin:0;
}

.top_menu li {
margin:0px 0 0 5px ;
padding:0;
float:left;
height:100px;
list-style : none;
background : transparent url(../images/top_menu_left.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
opacity:0.6;
-ms-filter: "prodig:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=60)"; /* fix IE8   */
filter: apha(opacity = 60);                    /* fix IE7       */
-webkit-transition : all 0.4s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition : all 0.4s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition : all 0.4s ease-in-out;
-o-transition : all 0.4s ease-in-out;
transition : all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.top_menu li:hover {
opacity:1;
-ms-filter: "prodig:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)"; /* fix IE8  */
filter: apha(opacity = 100);                                               /* fix IE7       */
}

.top_menu li a {
display:block;
color: #24221E/*8c8c8c*/;
text-shadow:0 0 3px #fff;
background : transparent url(../images/top_menu_right.png) 100% 0 no-repeat;
text-decoration:none;
text-transform: none;
font-weight:bold;
font-size:90%;
margin-right:-13px;
padding: 60px 22px 4px 20px;
height:40px;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: change the color of the active menu item

Comment: Can you give me the HTML output of the menu?

Answer (score 1):

I see that you are using Joomla as a Content Management System and you have to use a class to style an item, for example `active`, and then you can use CSS to assign a different styling for this item.

```
.active {
    text-decoration: underline;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

If you want to change the color of the link you need to adress the a tag directly using the following code.

```
.active a {
   color: red;
}
```

You might find this answer also useful: [Joomla - how to hightlight the menu item for active page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3366417/joomla-how-to-hightlight-the-menu-item-for-active-page)

Comment: I just adapted my anwser a little bit.

Comment: Thank you, using your example I now have the active menu item underlined, but when I add color:#xxxxxx; it doesn't change the color?This is the problem I've been experiencing. Seems something in the css is preventing the color of the active menu item from being changed??

Comment: @user2149917 Please keep in mind that a later CSS definition overrides the definitions made bevore. So make sure that your `.active` class is the last class. In addition it you need to adress the a tag directly like `.active a`.

Comment: OK, I will mark as solved soon as I get this color to change. Changing .active to active a didn't resolve, in fact it made the underline go away. I moved .active {    text-decoration: underline;  
} to the bottom of the css file...I still have the active menu item underlined, but no color change. Now reading the joomla link you gave me....

Comment: @user2149917 Well I thought that this also worked. Can you please make a jsfiddle out of it? It really helps me to spot the little mistake.

Comment: ok I will do that, thanks so much stoyno....btw this is the template I'm trying to modify(light version): http://www.joomspirit.com/template-joomla/template_76/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=28&Itemid=109# It has different color themes, and is responsive so there are multiple style sheets for me to check. I'm using the "Mariner Red" theme. I'm not using the main menu, I'm using only the top menu instead.